# Neo4j Cypher query: "Unknown identifier" when RETURN DISTINCT

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why does this query work (albeit with duplicate rows):

```
START user=node(1197)
MATCH (user)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->()-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
RETURN post.Id, post.Image, post.Description
ORDER BY post.CreationTime DESC;
```

and this one doesn't (it returns the error `Unknown identifier 'post'`):

```
START user=node(1197)
MATCH (user)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->()-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
RETURN DISTINCT post.Id, post.Image, post.Description
ORDER BY post.CreationTime DESC;
```

The only difference is the `DISTINCT` keyword.

I found a workaround by using a `WITH` but it seems to me that I shouldn't have to do this.

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.0-M05. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is legit.

DISTINCT removes the possibility to order by properties that are not mentioned in the DISTINCT clause, sine they might be collapsed (e.g. if there is 3 records with post.CreationTime lumped into one post.Id bucket with DISTINCT, which one should be ordered by?). To get a working query, include post.CreationTime in the DISTINCT like:

```
START user=node(1197)
MATCH (user)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->()-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
RETURN DISTINCT post.Id, post.Image, post.Description, post.CreationTime
ORDER BY post.CreationTime DESC;
```

This is not obvious though, so I raised https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1322 to make it into the docs - thanks for pointing it out!